# How should I go about alleviating the cin that occurs twice?

Tags: c++, cin

This is a bmi code I made in c++. However when I choose to output for male (1). It will ask for the height and weight twice. I am really confused and I have tried changing the code around, changing it to else, and even using switch statements. Can someone clarify this to me? If I choose to use else statement, The output after the input completely disappears and it ends the program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double height;
double weight;
double bmi;
int gender;
cout <<"Please enter your gender.(1 for female) (2 for male)\n";
cin >>gender;
if (gender = 1){
     cout<<"Please enter your height in metres. ";
    cin>>height;
    cout<<"Please enter your weight in kg. ";
    cin>>weight;
    bmi=weight/(height*height);
     if (bmi <= 19){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Underweight. You need to eat more.";
    return 0;
    }
     if(bmi >= 20 && bmi <= 24){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Normal. All good, please maintain.";
    return 0;
    }
     if(bmi >= 25 && bmi <= 29){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Overweight. You need to control your diet and do exercise.";
    return 0;
    }
     if(bmi > 29){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Obese!! Please see your dietician for advice on proper diet and exercise.";
    return 0;
    }
}
 if(gender = 2){
    cout<<"Please enter your height in metres. ";
    cin>>height;
    cout<<"Please enter your weight in kg. ";
    cin>>weight;
    bmi=weight/(height*height);
     if (bmi <= 20){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Underweight. You need to eat more.";
    return 0;
    }
    if(bmi >= 21 && bmi <= 25){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Normal. All good, please maintain.";
    return 0;
    }
    if(bmi >= 26 && bmi <= 30){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Overweight. You need to control your diet and do exercise.";
    return 0;
    }
    if(bmi > 30){
    cout <<"Your bmi is "<<bmi<<endl;
    cout <<"Obese!! Please see your dietician for advice on proper diet and exercise.";
    return 0;
    }
 }


}
```

Comment: [Please turn on your compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Z6tf-M)

Comment: @RishabhAnkit The code shown is not fine. There are some standard assignment-in-condition bugs.

Comment: *"when I choose to output for male (1)"* -- What about your other cases? What happens if you choose gender 2? Gender 3? More comprehensive testing (plus compiler warnings) should give you a better picture of your situation. (Stepping through the code with a debugger is another productive avenue.)

Comment: Change `gender = 1` to `gender == 1`

Comment: Hmm... one issue is the lack of effort put into a [mre], but there's also the fact that this is a typo. Or maybe treat this as a duplicate?

Comment: Which dupe to choose: [If statements triggering when conditions aren't met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22870330/if-statements-triggering-when-conditions-arent-met), [Why does my C++ implementation of pnpoly always return true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22995371/why-does-my-c-implementation-of-pnpoly-always-return-true), or [Why isn't my if/else statement producing the desired results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447990/why-isnt-my-if-else-statement-producing-the-desired-results)

Answer (score 0):

You got mixed up between `=` and `==`. The first is *assignment*, use that when you want to change that value of a variable. The second is *equality*, use that when you want to compare a variable with a value.

In other words

```
if (gender = 1)
```

should be

```
if (gender == 1)
```

And the same for

```
if (gender = 2)
```

which should be

```
if (gender == 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue, as pointed by others, was use of assignment operator instead of equality operator. Apart from suggesting you to enable your compiler warnings, I think that you should try reducing the size of your code by removing duplicate statements. You can get some hint from this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double height;
    double weight;
    double bmi;
    int    gender;

    const struct BMI {
        int under;
        int good;
        int over;
    } data[] = {{}, {20, 25, 29}, {21, 26, 30}};

    std::cout << "Please enter your gender (1 for female, 2 for male) : ";
    std::cin >> gender;
    std::cout << "Please enter your height (in metres) : ";
    std::cin >> height;
    std::cout << "Please enter your weight (in kg) : ";
    std::cin >> weight;

    bmi = weight / (height * height);
    std::cout << "Your BMI is : " << bmi << std::endl;

    if (gender != 1 or gender != 2) {
        std::cout << "Sorry we have no data for your gender!";
        return 0;
    }

    if (bmi < data[gender].under)
        std::cout << "Underweight. You need to eat more!";
    else if (bmi < data[gender].good)
        std::cout << "Normal. All good, please maintain!";
    else if (bmi < data[gender].over)
        std::cout << "Overweight. You need to control your diet and do exercise!";
    else
        std::cout << "Obese!! Please see your dietician for advice on proper diet and exercise.";

    return 0;
}
```

PS: You've mentioned that you tried using `switch-case`. Well, there you must have forgot to put `break` statement at end of each case label.